# Do mathematical equations require punctuation?

Tags: punctuation

**Mathematicians rarely heed the advice of grammarians.** In mathematical writing, one often places equations in a numbered environment outside of the inline text. Consider the following example.

```
Define f to be the function,  
       f(x) = sin x              (1) 
where x is to take values in [0,pi].
```

Although one rarely finds correct punctuation or consistent grammar in math textbooks or [online](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions), I'm inclined to be as anal as physically possible in my Ph.D. thesis and consult the appropriate authorities in the matter.

*What is the correct protocol for punctuation in the numbered equation environment?*

In particular, should there be a comma after "sin x"?

Comment: Many mathematicians have pretty strong opinions about punctuation and grammar!  See for instance [this mathoverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6675/periods-and-commas-in-mathematical-writing).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Donald Knuth [seems to agree](http://tex.loria.fr/typographie/mathwriting.pdf) that mathematical writing deserves good punctuation (see pages 5 and 6 at that link for examples of a period and comma following formulas). It's in Wikipedia's [Manual of Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aManual_of_Style_%28mathematics%29#Punctuation_after_formulae) as well, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematics texts require special care, because many punctuation symbols have special meaning in a mathematical context. It's for that reason that equations are often not included inline, and why you shouldn't try to do fancy things like including punctuation inside parentheses in a mathematical text.

In other words, I see nothing wrong with the text that you quoted, and I think that a mathematical text which *avoided* this sort of thing would be much harder to use than the usual.